# MediaPlayer audio gets cut of sometimes, but not always

Tags: android

I am playing an audio file like this:

```
        MediaPlayer player;
        player=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
        player.setLooping(false);

        player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {      
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player)
            {  
                player.release();       
            }            

        }); 
        player.start();
```

The issue is that sometimes it cuts the audio off in the middle (or the start and plays no more). If I reboot the phone the problem seems to be fixed but occurs again after some time. Could someone tell me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Thee code looks right. Have You tried MediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener()? What logcat says?

Comment: Nope. Not tried that. Let me try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `player.prepare()` before `player.start()`

And to have a better overview of how the MediaPlayer works, take a look at this state diagram :

http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif

Comment: if you are using create; you do not need to call prepare: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html (search for "no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you")

Comment: @KaanYy Yes I go in the source code and you're right! I made an app using a media player a long time ago, and it seemed that calling prepare has solved the problem for me (I can't remember why but yes that's strange, isn't it?) and that's why I answered this.